# Fail to unregister Signal account

Tags: signals

I've uninstalled the messaging app Signal on my android mobile and tried to unregister my phone number at https://signal.org/signal/unregister/ using a browser for a couple for days now. I am supposed to receive a verification code by call or SMS but I always encountered a "Failed to connect to the server" response. Any help on how to unregister would be much appreciated.